# How to know if logback configuration file has loaded?

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I am new to SLF4j and I don't know if the logback.xml file has loaded properly or not. The logback.xml file is in PROJECTNAME/src/main/java where all my packages are found.

My questions are:

1. How can I know if the configuration file has properly loaded or not
   ?
2. How can restrict the logging only from an explicit set of class,
   only to avoid logging from libraries

Answer (score 4):

You can add the `debug="true"` attribute to the `<configuration>` element to enable debug of the logback configuration. It will print the configuration to the console. See https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#dumpingStatusData.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, if the configuration file is loaded properly, you will see results in log file or console, depending on your configuration.

By default, logback searches file in src/main/resources instead of src/main/java if I remember correctly.

In the configuration file, you can define log lever on a specific logger. Normally you'll still want to see logs of the libraries, but maybe only WARN or ERROR, so you could set the root level to WARN/ERROR, and add a logger of your root package with DEBUG/INFO level.

Also, use a logback-test file (under src/test/resources) for your own dev environment.